# Get the number of divisors using combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers

I am trying to get the number of divisors of an integer by using its prime decomposition and combinatorial reasoning.

Let $\sigma_0(n)$ be the function that returns the number of divisors of $n$ (more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). 
Let $N$ be the prime decomposition of $n$, such as: $$N = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{\alpha_i} = p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_r^{\alpha_r}$$ where $p$ is a prime number and $\alpha$ is an integer.
We admit that:
$$\sigma_0(N) = \prod_{i=1}^r(1+\alpha_i) = (1+\alpha_1)...(1+\alpha_r)$$

Now let's suppose we have: $$N_0 = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{\alpha} = p_1^{\alpha}...p_r^{\alpha}$$ where $\alpha$ is always the same exponent.
We want to make a divisor of $n$ based on its prime decomposition $N_0$. We first take $k$ factors: number of possibilities $r$ choose $k$. It remains to fix the exponent: number of possibilities $\alpha^k$.
Thus by combinatorial reasoning we have deduced that: $$\sigma_0(N_0) = \sum_{k=0}^r \binom{r}{k}\alpha^k$$

For example, let's take $N_0 = 3³\times5³$ As said above, we should find $\sigma_0(N_0) = (3+1)(3+1) = 16.$
We have:
$\sigma_0(N_0) = \sum_{k=0}^r \binom{r}{k}\alpha^k \\
\sigma_0(N_0) = \sum_{k=0}^2 \binom{2}{k}3^k \\
\sigma_0(N_0) = \binom{2}{0}3^0 + \binom{2}{1}3^1 + \binom{2}{2}3^2 \\
\sigma_0(N_0) = 1+6+9 \\
\sigma_0(N_0) = 16$

So it seems to be correct (there are more examples).
Now things get a little more difficult when $\alpha$ is not necessarily identical:
$$N_1 = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{\alpha_i} = p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_r^{\alpha_r}$$
We should have something like that:
$$\sigma_0(N_1) = \sum_{k=0}^r \binom{r}{k}u_k$$ which must be equivalent to:
$$\prod_{i=1}^r(1+\alpha_i) =  (1+\alpha_1)...(1+\alpha_r)$$ My question is, is it possible to determine what $u_k$ is equal to depending on $k$ and $\alpha_i$ ?

Comment: Are you looking for a combinatorical proof of the formula for the number of divisors you already mentioned ? I think, this formula can easily enough be understood. Do you search for an alternative formula ?

Comment: Hard to see this working, since the possible exponents now depend on *which* of the prime factors you select.

Comment: Yes, I'm searching for an alternative formula.

Comment: Note that your expression is just $(1+\alpha)^r$ by the binomial theorem.

Comment: Lava, look carefully at Lulu's first comment. I think it completely answers (negatively) your question.

Comment: Oh OK, so it might not be possible at all? Is there another formula that uses combinatics and is equivalent to or explains $\sigma_0(N) = \prod_{i=1}^r(\alpha_i+1)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with something close to my question but not a real answer since it is impossible to solve.

Let's suppose: $$N = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{\alpha_i}$$
like $N_1 = 2³\times3²\times5$. We notice that $\sigma_0(N) = \sigma_0(2³)\times\sigma_0(3²)\times\sigma_0(5)$, because in order to make a divisor we have the number of divisors we can make with $2³$ times the number of divisors we can make with $3²$ and so on as possibilities (and also because $\sigma_0(mn) = \sigma_0(m)\times\sigma_0(n)$ which is just logical).

We know how to compute $\sigma_0(p^\alpha)$ from the formula mentioned above: $$\sigma_0(p^\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^1\binom{1}{k}\alpha^k$$
Thus in our example we now have:
$$\sigma_0(N_1) = \sum_{k=0}^1\binom{1}{k}3^k\sum_{k=0}^1\binom{1}{k}2^k\sum_{k=0}^1\binom{1}{k}1^k = 4\times3\times2 = 24$$

Now, we may conclude with this overall formula: 
If $p_i$ is a prime and $\alpha_i$ is a positive integer and $$N = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{\alpha_i}$$
then:
$$\sigma_0(N) = \prod_{i=1}^r\sum_{k=0}^1\binom{1}{k}\alpha_i^k$$
Like it was said before:
$$\sum_{k=0}^1\binom{1}{k}\alpha^k = 1+\alpha$$
by the binomial theorem, hence:
$$\sigma_0(N) = \prod_{i=1}^r(1+\alpha_i)$$